# scp works fine, but rsync does not

Tags: 16.04, ssh, rsync

Trying to pull some mkv files from my raspberry-pi, but rsync doesn't seem to work, while the same remote path works fine with scp. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

**rsync**

```
vinicius@Inspiron-5537:/media/vinicius/C8A0CA48A0CA3CA6$ rsync --protect-args -aP "user@server:/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads/Treze\ Dias\ Longe\ do\ Sol\ 2017\ -\ Minissérie\ \(720p\)\ WWW.LAPUMiAFiLMES.COM" .
receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads/Treze\ Dias\ Longe\ do\ Sol\ 2017\ -\ Minissérie\ \(720p\)\ WWW.LAPUMiAFiLMES.COM" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
vinicius@Inspiron-5537:/media/vinicius/C8A0CA48A0CA3CA6$
```

**scp**

```
vinicius@Inspiron-5537:/media/vinicius/C8A0CA48A0CA3CA6$ scp "user@server:/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads/Treze\ Dias\ Longe\ do\ Sol\ 2017\ -\ Minissérie\ \(720p\)\ WWW.LAPUMiAFiLMES.COM/*.mkv" .
Treze.Dias.Longe.do.Sol.2017.S01E01.720p.WEBRip.x264.NACIONAL-WWW.LAPUMiAFiLMES.COM.mkv                               1%   13MB   1.7MB/s   09:24 ETA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scp uses ssh per definition, `rsync` does not. You have to tell rsync to use ssh with `--rsh=ssh`. E.g

`rsync -av --rsh=ssh user@server:/file /filex`

For more information, see man `rsync`.